# Return function not being found in global scope

Tags: javascript, function, return

```
var setup = function(){
    console.log("xyz");
    return function goBack(){
        console.log("It's actually abc");
    }
}
```

Now, on calling setup() in the global scope, "xyz" is being shown in the console, but the returning function(goBack) is not being appended in the global scope. Shouldn't I be able to access goBack from the global scope once I execute setup() ?

Comment: No, this is not how javascript works...

Comment: @OmriLuzon Thanks for the super helpful comment. Eternally grateful for your help. All my doubts are clear. :)

Answer (score 2):

`setup` is returning a function.

To access it, first call `var result = setup()`. Now you have `goBack` stored in the `result` variable.

You can now use `result()` to call `goBack` from outside the scope of `setup`.

Comment: I get what you are saying. But, what happens when I simply execute setup() without storing it in a 'result' variable. What I want to understand here is : Where does 'goBack' go?

Comment: In that case, `goBack` would still be returned and picked up by the garbage collector as no reference was made. Without making a reference to it, there is no way to call it.

Comment: What you could do, is call `setup()()`. This would call setup, and them immediately call `goBack` as it is returned from the first function. It is a form of immediate invocation.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I am new to JavaScript and haven't heard of the garbage collector. Will look it up. Also didn't know I could call setup like setup()(). Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

no, you're returning it from `setup` - the name `goBack` is irrelevant. You would need to call it on the return value from `setup`:

```
var foo = setup();
foo();// calls the function youve named `goBack`
// goBack() does not exist here.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access this function goBack like this

```
var setup = function(){
console.log("xyz");
return function goBack(){
    console.log("It's actually abc");
}(); // IIFE here
}

setup(); // returns xyz , its actually abc
```

As you see here , I have made the goBack into an IIFE and called setup() in the global scope.

All you needed to do was invoke the function that you were returning.